# Finding X, Y of nodes in feature layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, latitude-longitude, features

I have a map document in ArcMap and I want to find X and Y of my nodes in a special feature layer. I look through my access database and I just find the Shape Index table which has MinGX, MinGY, MaxGX, MaxGY. I need to find the X , Y of my nodes.

Generally, from what source is ArcMap locating the nodes on the map?

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the values e.g. with python by using the field calculator. The type of calculation depends on the type of feature layer but as you are talking about nodes I assume that you have line features. The expressions for the calculation of the different min and max values would be:
 `x1 = shape.firstpoint.x
  x2 = shape.lastpoint.x
  y1 = shape.firstpoint.y
  y2 = shape.lastpoint.y`

You could populate corresponding fields with these expressions or use them in a script once you have a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add x-y coords to shape files you could install xtools pro. The free tools will allow you to calculate the x-y of a point, the start / centre/ end x-y of a line and the centroid x-y of a polygon.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the ADD XY Points Tool in the Arc ToolBOx in the ArcMap if you are not a programmer. That should add points at the nodes as you mentioned.

Comment: Are you refering to the Add XY coordinates tool (only use for point features)? There is no ADD XY Points tool.

Comment: Oh yeah I was referring to the samefor which you need to convert the lines to points then just add the coordinates using spatial join.